# WPF DataGridCell Template with TextBlock - Binding?

Tags: wpf, replace, textblock, contentpresenter, datagridcell

i replace the `ContentPresenter` in the `DataGridCell`'s `Template` with a `TextBlock` an now i search for the correct `Binding` to the content.

The normal way is `Text="{TemplateBinding Content}` for the `TextBlock` - it doesn't work. Also `Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content, Mode=TwoWay}"` doesn't work correct.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Note that when `Content` is a string, `ContentPresenter` automatically generates a `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Suppose you have changed the `DataGridCell Template` to the following

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
        <!--<ContentPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/> -->
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Since you removed the `ContentPresenter`, the `DataGridCell` has no way of displaying its `Content`. It's still there though. The `DataGridCell.Content`
is a `TextBlock` containing your original `Text` and the `TextBlock` in the `Template` is another.

So you'll get the correct `Text` by binding it to the `Content.Text` property of the `TemplatedParent`

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                          Path=Content.Text}"/>
```

So, to sum it up. This works

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
                                  Path=Content.Text}"/>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The data context of the data grid cell should be the data itself. So the binding should simply be:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
```

Comment: The `DataGridCell` has the same `DataContext` as the `DataGridRow` so you'll need a path. And if you want this to be generic, you can't set a path. I don't think this works